# connections are not closing in oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, datasource

Problem
We have a java web application connected to Oracle database configured through Websphere application server.
Connections are of Datasource connections, not plain jdbc connections(DriverManager.getConnection(), so no need to do con.colse()).
Connection pool size is 10. Number of connections which are open in database side is more than 500. v$session  table is showing
morethan 500 connections are open. we are connecting to the db throught only one user. All connections belong to one 
user. My Question is Why the connections are not closed after idle time or tranasaction over ? Most of the connections
are idle and not using for running any sql query against the databse, but the connections are open.
Is this a websphere setting or Oracel DBA setting ? How to configure Websphere to use the connection from connection pool  only?
How to do the DBA Oracle setup to kill the connection after session out time or default time (say 30 min), not manually? 
Please help 
Thanks,
Krishna
ekrishna10@gmail.com

Comment: You need to `close()` the connection when you are done with it. What made you think otherwise?

Comment: Thanks Elliott Frisch, This is bit old application,Recently the issue of connections occuring. I have checked the code , we are closing all the connections  generically in one method closeJDBCObjects() and calling in all places where new connections are created in finally block.

Comment: Take a look at my blog post [here](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/clean-up-after-yourself.html). And then make sure that you are doing what you say you are.

Comment: Any help from DB side, as the connections are are idle at most of the time , not running any sql, why cant Oracle DB has option of closing connection after some time(session time or default time say 30 min ? Please let me know if any such option.

Comment: Check with your DBA (or server fault). You can also restart your application server (with corresponding down-time) periodically.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you are using a DataSource in no way means that your code doesn't need to close a connection when it is done with it.  No matter how you get the connection, you need to ensure that you close the connection when you're done with it.

The [DataSource tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html), for example, explicitly points out that you need to close your connections and suggests something like

```
try {
    Connection con = ds.getConnection(username, password);
    // ... code to use the pooled
    // connection con
} catch (Exception ex {
    // ... code to handle exceptions
} finally {
    if (con != null) con.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Justin Cave, This is bit old application,Recently the issue of connections occuring. I have checked the code , we are closing all the connections  generically in one method closeJDBCObjects() and calling in all places where new connections are created in finally block.

Comment: @krishna - If the application server has 500 connections to the database and the connection pool in the middle tier isn't configured to want 500 connections, then it is almost certainly the case that you're not closing your connections properly somewhere in the application.